# Arrayindex out of bound in java

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am not able to figure out that why i am getting the Array index out of bound exception in this code

```
class sample
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int a[]={1,2,3};
    int b[]=new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      b[a[i]]=a[i]/*getting array out of bound exception*/
     }
  } 
 }
```

Comment: a[3] to a[9] not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop has to rather be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   if (a[i] < b.length) {
       b[a[i]] = a[i];
   }
}
```

because you're copying the values of `a` into `b`, not vice versa.

Comment: this is still dangerous, as you reference the array b with the content of a and the number could be a lot bigger than 9. You need another if before you access b[a[i]]

Comment: Thanks @slfan. I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`a` has a length of 3, so the only valid indices are 0,1 and 2.

Therefore `a[i]` is out of bounds when i > 2.

Answer (score 0):

array a[] contains only 3 elements, but for loop iterates 10 times. so it raising ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException.
use : for(int i=0;i<3;i++) or for(int i=0;i